# websocket echo ERROR: undefined

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, websocket

I have downloaded glassfish and JSF samples. localhost:8888/websocket-echo/ works fine on glassfish. When I copied the war file to Tomcat I get the page but then **ERROR: undefined**. ?

Answer (score 1):

They will never work, differnt apis

Answer (score 0):

Check the service enpoint and the corresponding html web socket url. I have got this error when I was trying the example on tomcat. The service endpoint was /example/chat, hence the client side (html) url should be ws://localhost:8080/$web-app$/example/chat.